# 数詞 + も suitable location

Tags: counters, numbers

How should I determine which place I need to locate 「数詞{すうし}　+ も」? From my text book example:

> 1: 毎年{まいとし}**何百枚{なんびゃくまい}も**年賀状{ねんがじょう}を出{だ}します

数詞も is now located in front of the noun 年賀状.

> 2: 卵{たまご}を**六{むっ}つも**食{た}べた

Now 数詞も is located in front of the verb 食べた. I'm getting quite confused with this.

Answer (score 4):

Both of your example sentences sound fine. You could place "numeral + counter + も" before or after "noun + を".

You'd usually place "numeral + counter" after "noun + を・が", as in:

> **卵を６個**食べた。
>   **年賀状を１００枚**出します。

And you can keep the same word order when you use も, as in:

> 卵を６個**も**食べた。
>   年賀状を何百枚**も**出します。

It's also grammatical to place "numeral + counter" before "noun + を・が", as in:

> **６個卵を**食べた。
>   **１００枚年賀状を**出します。

Here again you can keep the same word order with も:

> ６個**も**卵を食べた。
>   何百枚**も**年賀状を出します。

---

The same applies to だけ、くらい、は、しか～ない、何～か、 etc. eg:

> 卵を１個**だけ**食べた。
>   １個**だけ**卵を食べた。
>
> 卵が２個**しかない**。
>   ２個**しか**卵が**ない**。
>
> 卵が**何**個**か**割れた。
>   **何**個**か**卵が割れた。

Comment: Do you really use 〜個 to count eggs you're eating?  It makes it sound like you're eating them whole...

Comment: @istrasci as opposed to just つ? That would imply some difference?

Comment: @Leebo:  *I* would infer a difference, but that's just how I mentally "picture" 〜個.  I always learned one of its usages is to count "small (often round) objects".  I know it's broader than that, but I guess my mind kind of automatically limits it to that.  And eggs are round, so that's where my brain went.

Answer (score 0):

For example, in the case of 私は昨日、友達の家で三個も林檎を食べた。

私は昨日、友達の家で**三個も**林檎を食べた。

**三個も**私は昨日、友達の家で林檎を食べた。

私は**三個も**昨日、友達の家で林檎を食べた。

私は昨日、**三個も**友達の家で林檎を食べた。

私は昨日、友達の家で林檎を**三個も**食べた。

私は昨日、友達の家で林檎を食べた、**三個も**。

These are almost same meaning and you can choose the one you like. That is to say, you can locate adverbs which indicates time and number everywhere but when they are located in the first and end of the sentence, I feel it is emphasized. By the by, I chose the first one.